# overflow:scroll not working on flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three div's:

- Div 01
- Div 02 - fixed width 300px
- Div 03

Div 01 and Div 03 should be same width.

Example:

- If viewport is 1000px, Div 01 width=350px and Div 03 width=350px,
- If viewport is 800px, Div 01 width=250px and Div 03 width=250px.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 auto;
  height: 400px;
}
.middle {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.</div>
  <div class="middle">sd</div>
  <div class="flex-item">sd</div>
</div>
```

**This is work as I want. But I need to add `overflow: scroll` to flex-item class.**

After adding this, it does not work. How to solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want **Div 01** and **Div 03** to be the same width, then `flex: 1 auto` is not a reliable tool. The `flex-grow: 1` component will size the flex item based on the available space in the container, which could vary. You need to define a width for the `flex-item` class.

For the flex items to scroll vertically, you need to specify a `height` or `flex-basis` (when `flex-direction` is `column`).

For the flex items to scroll horizontally, you need to specify `width` or `flex-basis` (when `flex-direction` is `row`). You also need to add `white-space: nowrap`.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
}

.flex-item {
    /* flex: 1 auto; */
    flex: 0 0 350px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
    height: 400px;
}

.middle {
    /* width: 300px; */
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    background: aqua;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.</div>
  <div class="middle">sd</div>
  <div class="flex-item">sd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ank60d7x/) can help you!
To make `overflow:scroll` work use the below attributes:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis:0;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a similar issue, where the scroller was not visible, the reason for that was `justify-content: flex-end`.
Once I removed it the code started working as expected.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I had this issue, and I finally stumbled across this answer and it DID answer the question, at least for me.  Thank you Mohammed Yousuff

Comment: @Yunnosch, I do see a answer here.  You are right, the original question has `justify-content` set to `space-around`.  However, if you only change `justify-content` to `flex-end`, which is VERY similar to the original question, the other solutions don't have the same effect.  I understand that this could be extracted out to another question technically, but this answer to a very slight variation of the original question was very helpful to me, so I thought I'd leave a comment, as you suggest, for others that may follow the same path I did to find it.

Comment: @JakeSmith Ok, thanks for that input, I needed it because I myself am not that knowlegeable on this topic. Please keep that comment up, even if I delete my comments (inclduing this one after some time....).

Answer (score 0):

When you use flexbox all your div need to be in the flex flow.

So you better use `flex: 1 1 300px` instead of `width: 300px`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background:red;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.middle {
  background:blue;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
   This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
  </div>
  <div class="middle">sd</div>
  <div class="flex-item">sd</div>
</div>
```